# Zend Select NOT IN

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I have two tables with related data, and I want to select all the records from one table which do not exist in the other table, plus some other criteria on the related table, as follows (123 is just for illustration purposes):

```
TABLE A
    ID
    SOMETHING

TABLE B
    TABLE_A_ID
    TABLE_C_ID
    SOMETHING
```

My query, run directly against the data, would be as follows

```
SELECT A.SOMETHING 
    FROM A 
    WHERE A.ID NOT IN (
        SELECT 
            B.TABLE_A_ID AS ID 
            FROM B 
            WHERE TABLE_C_ID = 123
    );
```

How can I run this in Zend?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can run direct sql, using `$db->query()`; yours would simply be:

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT A.SOMETHING 
FROM A 
WHERE A.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT 
        B.TABLE_A_ID AS ID 
        FROM B 
        WHERE TABLE_C_ID = ?
)", $id);
```

**EDIT**: To answer whether this can be done with the object notation, yes:

```
$sub_select = $zdb->select()
                  ->from("b", array("table_a_id AS id"))
                  ->where("table_c_id = ?", 'a');
$select = $zdb->select()
              ->from("a", array("something"))
              ->where("id NOT IN ?", $sub_select);
print $select->__toString();
```

gives

```
SELECT `a`.`something` FROM `a`
WHERE (id NOT IN
    (SELECT `b`.`table_a_id` AS `id` FROM `b` WHERE (table_c_id = 'a')))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART?