# Zend Framework create a sql function

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I would like to create a sql query in Zend Framework in the Abstract.php or in model? but I have a hard time figure out how to do it. I am new in zend framework.

The query that I want to create looks like that:

```
delete from users where id not in(select * from(select min(n.id)from users n group by n.email)x);
```

But in zend:

```
$results = $db->query('delete
                from users
                where id not in(
                    select * from(
                        min(n.id)
                        from users n
                        group by n.email
                )x)');
```

Look like the $db got a undefined variable, what kind of database function should the db call? My database is being call in the application.ini

Comment: That's not even the slightest bit valid PHP code. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5380654/1902010 for something similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Oh thank you, but how do I call the delete

Comment: I'd imagine you change `select()` to `delete()`, but you'd want to learn PHP and read the documentation before you go doing destructive changes to data like that.

Comment: Which database adapter are you using? It should be set in your ini file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to write this syntex for executing your custom query..

```
$db->getAdapter()->query('delete
                from users
                where id not in(
                    select * from(
                        min(n.id)
                        from users n
                        group by n.email
                )x)');
```